# Implementing memory monger method for pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I want to implement memory monger method as described in this paper [Training Deep Nets with Sublinear Memory Cost](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.06174.pdf). The code that implements that method for mxnet framework can be found [here](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet-memonger).

My question is, this memory monger method is suitable for symbolic graphs like the ones in Theano and Tensorflow, but the graphs in pytorch are dynamic, so can this method be applied for pytorch ?